# Why do some ships have better stats shown in orange?

Tags: wipeout-omega-collection

In the *Wipeout HD* gameplay mode, each team has one ship available in multiple unlockable liveries.  However, for many, in fact *most* of the teams, there is a second ship available above the first one, also with unlockable liveries.

The upper ships have the same base starts as the lower ones with what appear to be stat bonuses displayed in orange at the ends of applicable graphs.

What are the meaning of these orange bars?  Simple stat buffs would make these ships objectively better than the lower ones, so I'm guessing it's not that simple.
[image: Icaras variant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the orange bar represents an additional bonus on the base value of those stats. From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/WipeOut/comments/6gxd7x/hdfury_what_does_the_orange_stat_mean_when_youre/):

> The HD Fury ships have slightly better stats than their HD counterparts. **That's what the orange represents. Just an extension of the original stats.**
>
> they're not "slightly better," as there are many more stats affecting the physics that are withheld. They are slightly different, however, and **the orange marks the area where you'll notice improvements**. This doesn't mean the Fury ships are categorically superior, however, as there are other factors that play into their raceability (including shape and size, etc.)

This is also supported in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/202535-wipeout-omega-collection/75429532?page=1), where users are discussing specific ships, but note the meaning of the orange bar:

> Those two just do not have a variant from the Fury expansion (**the stat boosts in orange/red**).

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>